# How do I get view mode

Tags: views, 8, nodes

Is there an easy way to get `node's` `view mode` from `entity.view`?

```
function classier_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    $vars['rows'][0]['#rows'][0]['#view_mode'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the view mode of a node you probably want to use a different hook.

```
function classier_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $view_mode = $vars['view_mode'];
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution, but i need get view mode form view